# QDateTimeEdit установить пустое значение

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qdatetimeedit

Подскажите пожалуйста как полностью удалить текст из `QDateTimeEdit`?
В моей БД есть колонки с датами в формате **`TEXT`**, в этих колонках есть **`пустые ячейки`**. 
Мне необходимо показать пустой `QDateTimeEdit` если в БД ячейка пуста.

Я нашел вот такой пример:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500189/correct-use-of-the-clear-method-on-qdatetimeedit/72732839#72732839
Но он работает только при нажатии кнопки, а мне нужно удалить значение когда открывается окно по условию.
Спасибо.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я просто соединил ваше желание с кодом, который вам подходит и ничего более.

```
import sys
import datetime
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class DateTimeEditDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DateTimeEditDemo, self).__init__()
        
        self.vlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        date_time_str = '18-09-2022 01:55:19'
        self._str_date_time(date_time_str)
        
        date_time_str = ''                                  # <----
        self._str_date_time(date_time_str)
        
        date_time_str = '24-06-2022 08:57:00'
        self._str_date_time(date_time_str)
        
        date_time_str = ''                                  # <----
        self._str_date_time(date_time_str)
        
    def _str_date_time(self, date_time_str):
        try:
            date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
            #print (f"{date_time_obj} --- {type(date_time_obj)}")
            dateTimeEdit = QDateTimeEdit(date_time_obj)
            dateTimeEdit.setDisplayFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        except Exception as e:
            dateTimeEdit = QDateTimeEdit()
            QTimer.singleShot(10, lambda: self.clearDate(dateTimeEdit))

        self.vlayout.addWidget(dateTimeEdit)     

    def clearDate(self, dateTimeEdit):
        dateTimeEdit.findChild(QLineEdit).setText('')      

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app  = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = DateTimeEditDemo()
    w.resize(300, 120)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Comment: @elKryack пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Просто пустое значение QDateTimeEdit не поддерживает, но можно сделать чтобы дата при отображении скрывалась. Это можно сделать двумя способами:

1. Установить стиль для виджета, делающий текст прозрачным
2. Программно скрыть отображение даты

Код с примером:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDateTime
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # setting geometry
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 400)
        self.datetimeedit = QDateTimeEdit(self)
        self.datetimeedit.setGeometry(100, 100, 150, 35)
        # Можно применить стиль для виджета (сделать текст прозрачным), если установлена минимальная дата,
        # но в этом случае при выделении текста в виджете, дата будет видна
        self.datetimeedit.setDateTime(QDateTime.fromTime_t(0))
        self.datetimeedit.setStyleSheet('QWidget[text="01.01.1970 07:00"] { color: rgb(0,0,0,0);}')
        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText("hide/show")
        self.button.setGeometry(255, 100, 80, 35)
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.showHideDateTime())
        self.show()

    def showHideDateTime(self):
        # Или можно программно скрыть виджет, отображающий дату (в детях QDateTimeEdit есть обычный QLineEdit)
        edit = self.datetimeedit.findChild(QLineEdit, "qt_spinbox_lineedit")
        if edit.isVisible():
            edit.hide()
        else:
            edit.show()

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, но мне нужно именно удалить значение, потому что затем нужно будет сохранить это значение в БД, и если оно не будет отредактировано пользователем то, как я думаю, автоматически сохранится стандартная дата, для моей программы это 2022-01-01 00:00.
Может быть есть какой-то пример переопределения класса QDateTimeEdit, чтобы добавить в него метод удаления значения? Я недавно занимаюсь программированием и не очень понимаю как это сделать.